# How to create empty body Collider 2D in Unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine

**Describe Problem:** Ok so I'm trying to remake Flappy Bird and intend to add some new features to it. When my bird died ( he bumps his head to the ground or the pipe ), an external force is applied to him to make him bounce off in the opposite direction. But there is one problem, he flies too far and is out of the scope of the camera's view. So, this leads to the main problem, I come up with the idea of creating Edge Collider around the camera ( like the Cinemachine Confiner component but for the player ) [See the image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XMfu8.png) . It works just fine but is there any way to achieve this in a more automatic way?

Comment: Reduce the force instead so it doesn't go flying off the screen??

Comment: Can't use your solution cuz I want him to collide with this collider :>>

Comment: What do you mean by more automatic? You created edge collider and set 4 points to it, that seems pretty straightforward. How do you imagine it being more automatic? :D What exactly should be easier here?

Comment: Typically you would have the pipes and background move in this type of game, so it should be ok to set up a static edge collider in your scene.